# How to validate serialized forms in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have created a form, and i'm serializing it and sending it to my MVC Action method............My jQuery Ajax script looks like this........

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var jsonObj = $('#form').serialize();
    alert(jsonObj);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../Doctor/AddDoctor',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "doctor": jsonObj }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Message);    
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown + " , Please try again");
        }
    });
    return false;



});
```

So i need to validate this form before i send it to the Action method..... How can i do that?............
I have found a code but i'm not really sure where i need to insert it.......
this is that code.......

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        Name: {
            required: true,
            //email: true
        },
        Charges: {
            required: true,
            //minlength: 5
        },
        WardId: {
            required: true,
            //minlength: 5
        },
        PhoneNo: {
            required: true,
            //minlength: 5
        }
    }
});
```

Can someone please show me where to insert this, to validate my form..........this is how my MVC form looks like.......................

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDoctor", "Doctor", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4></h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })*@
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> User ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })*@
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Doctor Speciality ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Charges, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Charges, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "Charges" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Charges)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WardId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WardId, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "WardId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WardId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "PhoneNo" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should validate the form before sending the Ajax request so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            // all the rules
        }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var $form = $('#form');

        if ($form.valid()) {

            var jsonObj = $form.serialize();
            alert(jsonObj);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../Doctor/AddDoctor',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "doctor": jsonObj }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.Message);    
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert("Error: " + errorThrown + " , Please try again");
                }
           });
       } else {
            alert('form is not valid!');
       }
       return false;

    });
}
```

Comment: sorry .... it didn't work..... now the page doesn't do anything...... it's frozen..

Comment: You should show the HTML code too.. in your code you have different ids for the form #myform and #form..

Comment: i corrected the id name to #form it still doesn't work

Comment: try putting everything around $(document).ready(function() { ALL JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE }

Comment: Does the page load? Do you see the form? check the errors in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71798/discussion-between-dayan-and-yanivel).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your submit click handler to this:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();

    var doctorForm = $('#form');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(doctorForm);
    doctorForm.validate();

    if (doctorForm.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Doctor/AddDoctor")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "doctor": jsonObj }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Message);    
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown + " , Please try again");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Still it wont work the page is frozen...... doesn't do anything....no errors as well

Comment: I've just edited my code to change the URL, as far as I'm aware you can't use relative paths in JQuery, but using `@Url.Content(relativePath)` will allow the server to render the path at runtime, which is effectively relative.

Comment: yes there is an error in my console..... it says 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'........... it points to this.... where i put my validation code.... $('#form').validate({

Comment: Have you got a link ref to the unobtrusive validation library in your Layout?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by unobtrusive validation library?

Comment: It should be included in your scripts section.